# Add ( + ) more button for multiple inputs

Tags: html, button, input, addition

i have a multiple input form to which i would like to add the feature where the first input is visible and the others are hidden and when Add more button is clicked, it will show the next input up to 8. I would like to keep the id's the way they are. 
How would i go about that? Thank you.

```
<label for="stop1">Stop 1 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop1" name="stop1" /><br />
<label for="stop2">Stop 2 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop2" name="stop2" /><br />
<label for="stop3">Stop 3 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop3" name="stop3" /><br />
<label for="stop4">Stop 4 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop4" name="stop4" /><br />
<label for="stop4">Stop 5 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop5" name="stop5" /><br />
<label for="stop6">Stop 6 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop6" name="stop6" /><br />
<label for="stop7">Stop 7 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop7" name="stop7" /><br />
<label for="stop8">Stop 8 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop8" name="stop8" /><br />
```

Thank you again.

Comment: You can use javascript.  I would recommend using jquery to append additional input elements as needed.

Comment: i looked around but haven't tried anything, i'm new to javascript and jquery. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    int countInput = 1;

    function showInput(){
        document.getElementById("stop"+(countInput +1)).style.display = 'block';
    }


function onLoadFunction(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
        var id = inputs[i].getAttribute("id"); 
        if ( id != "stop1" ) { 
            document.getElementById("stop"+countInput).style.display = 'block';
        }
    countInput++;
    }

    countInput = 1;

}
</script>



<label for="stop1">Stop 1 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop1" name="stop1" /><br />
<label for="stop2">Stop 2 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop2" name="stop2" /><br />
<label for="stop3">Stop 3 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop3" name="stop3" /><br />
<label for="stop4">Stop 4 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop4" name="stop4" /><br />
<label for="stop4">Stop 5 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop5" name="stop5" /><br />
<label for="stop6">Stop 6 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop6" name="stop6" /><br />
<label for="stop7">Stop 7 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop7" name="stop7" /><br />
<label for="stop8">Stop 8 :</label>
 <input type="text" id="stop8" name="stop8" /><br />

<button type="button" onclick="showInput"></button>
```

Just call the `onLoadFunction` from the onload atribbute of your page and it might works

Comment: hi Jeyvison, i just tried it and it doesn't work. i might be doing something wrong?

Comment: hey guys before you completely close this, i have been trying to accomplish this with jquery. Would anyone give it a look and let me know if it will work? Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/kngMg/

Comment: @im2shae can i do that for a dropdown list ?